# Trim decimal to 2 digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(((currentytd - PreviousYTD) / PreviousYTD) * 100)) + '%' as ytdGrowth from ytd
```

It is returning:
11.224300%

I would like to return:
11.22%

I am very new SQL so trying to find the correct way to accomplish this.

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2).......`

Comment: For rounding, use `round`. If you care about how the value is printed out, that's a job of the presentation layer, not the DB query, really.

Comment: @Luaan is indeed correct that this should be happening on the presentation layer, as by doing it on the SQL end, you're 1. doing potentially unneeded work (depending on how it's being presented, it might still have trailing zeros anyways) and 2. Making your SQL query more difficult to read.  The only way I'd personally consider doing it this way is if there is no presentation layer, and you're just running queries to copy/paste to a text document or something.

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),round((((currentytd - PreviousYTD) / PreviousYTD) * 100),2)) + '%' as ytdGrowth from ytd
```

Just add the `round(X,2)` to your query

Comment: ROUND should be applied before CONVERT

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: @JeffreyLazo Yup, take a look at ericZ's comment

Answer (score 1):

first convert to `decimal` at `2` precision (18,2) then `nvarchar`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(decimal(18,2),(((currentytd - PreviousYTD) / PreviousYTD) * 100))    ) + '%' AS ytdGrowth 
from ytd
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find `str()` useful:

```
SELECT str( ((currentytd - PreviousYTD) / PreviousYTD) * 100.0, 5, 2) + '%' as ytdGrowth
from ytd
```

Comment: Odd that this would be downvoted without a comment.

Comment: this won't consistently return 2 decimals

Comment: @Lamak . . . This does assume that the percentage value is less than 100% (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx), which I admit isn't specified in the question but it seems reasonable.

Comment: But you also gave it a length of `5`, so, for instance, `SELECT STR(999.4455454,5,2)` returns `999.4`

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer `CAST` when working with decimals

```
CAST (value as DECIMAL (9,2))
```

9 represents the total of characters, and 2 the number of characters after the decimal point

Comment: In your opinion, what's the difference between `CAST` and `CONVERT` in this case?

Comment: And you will get an error when you add  `+ '%'`, as the OP has.

Comment: Ha, didn't notice the symbol until you pointed it out @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Lamak Just personal preference, nothing else.

Comment: @edrodriguez ah, I thought that there was some other reason, since it was a "much more a better option"

Comment: @Lamak One of those huh...

Comment: Hey, if you don't have any real reason then you shouldn't mislead the op with things like `much better option`

Comment: @GordonLinoff BTW, Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: No need to get upset dude. It's just good to clarify that it's just your personal preference and if you have a reason then specify. Example I prefer `CAST()` because it's ANSI complient.

Comment: @Zane not upset at all my man, appreciate your comment though

Comment: And I prefer `CONVERT()` since most of the time I also have to supply the style attribute, which `CAST()` does not support.